# Forecasting a VECM using predict

Tags: var

I'm trying to forecasts time-series using a VECM with one endogenous and one exogenous variable (ideally both would be ex. but this doesn't seem to be possible), but keep running into errors. I've got 169 time-series and I'm trying to use the first 140 weeks to predict the last 29. See my code below:

```
#VECM with exogenous F
#read F and W matrix
Ffactor <- read_excel("FFactor.xlsx", col_names = FALSE)
Wfactor <- read_excel("Wmatrix.xlsx", col_names = FALSE)
Sales<-read_excel("SALES.xlsx")
Wfactor$mean <- rowMeans(Wfactor)
KC_model <- cbind(Sales$UnitSalesKC[1:169], Wfactor$mean)

F140 <- as.data.frame(Ffactor[1:140,])
 for (i in 1:1000)
{
  colnames(F140)[i]<-"f"
}
KC140 <- as.data.frame(KC_model[1:140,])

vecm <- ca.jo(KC140,type = "eigen", ecdet = "const", K = 2, dumvar = F140[1:140,1])
varr <- vec2var(vecm, r=1)#should be 2 because of 2nd order cointegration but it had to be 1
dumvar <- Ffactor[141:169,]
dumvar1 <- as.matrix(dumvar)

predictions <- predict(varr, dumvar=dumvar1[1:29], n.ahead=29)
predictions <- predict(varr, dumvar=dumvar1[1:29], n.ahead=29)
```

Running the first predict gives: Error in predict.vec2var(varr, dumvar = dumvar[1:29, 1], n.ahead = 29) : 
Column names of 'dumvar' do not match with column names in 'object$datamat'.

Running the second one gives: Error in predict.vec2var(varr, dumvar = dumvar1[1:29, 1], n.ahead = 29) : 
  Number of rows of 'dumvar' is not equal to 'n.ahead'.

However, calling nrow(dumvar) yields 29.

I've previously gotten error telling me dumvar should be a matrix, numeric or vector which is why I converted it into a matrix. Here's a sample of all the data needed to run the above code.

```
#head of KC_model
1 125489.0 -0.427423755
2 115475.0 -0.590675518
3 124298.0 -0.561800218
4 128443.0 -0.785542240
5 120610.0 -0.750909402

#head of FFactor
1 -0.251 
2 -0.0169
3 -0.0434
4 -0.0643
5  0.0215
```

Comment: Could you add some more tags?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
predictions <- predict(varr, dumvar=as.matrix.data.frame(F140[1:140,1]), n.ahead=29)
```

It worked for me.

Comment: Please reformat your answer with the code section.